# Transform a list of objects into a Map<Parent, List<Descendant>>

Tags: java, java-stream, grouping

I have a List of Containers, and each Container can have a single parent Container or no parent Container at all. I want to convert this list into a Map, where the key is the oldest ancestor / parent, and the value is a list of all descendants of that ancestor.

I have tried the following code, which almost works as expected, but it also collects children as parent keys if those children are also parents of other children:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Container c1 = new Container("c1");
    Container c11 = new Container("c1_1");
    Container c111 = new Container("c1_1_1");
    Container c12 = new Container("c1_2");
    c11.setParent(c1);
    c111.setParent(c11);
    c12.setParent(c1);

    Container c2 = new Container("c2");
    Container c21 = new Container("c2_1");
    Container c22 = new Container("c2_2");
    c21.setParent(c2);
    c22.setParent(c2);


    List<Container> containers = Lists.newArrayList(c1, c11, c111, c12, c2, c21, c22);

    System.out.println("All containers: " + containers);

    Map<Container, List<Container>> parentsAndChildren = containers.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(container -> container.getParent() == null ? container : container.getParent(), Collectors.mapping(container -> container, Collectors.toList())));

    System.out.println("Ancestor / Descendants: " + parentsAndChildren);
}

@Data
@RequiredArgsConstructor
private static final class Container {
    private final String key;
    private Container parent;

    public String toString() {
        return key;
    }
}
```

This results in the following output:

```
All containers: [c1, c1_1, c1_1_1, c1_2, c2, c2_1, c2_2]
Ancestor / Descendants: {c1_1=[c1_1_1], c2=[c2, c2_1, c2_2], c1=[c1, c1_1, c1_2]}
```

While the expected output is:

```
All containers: [c1, c1_1, c1_1_1, c1_2, c2, c2_1, c2_2]
Ancestor / Descendants: {c2=[c2_1, c2_2], c1=[c1_1, c1_1_1, c1_2]}
```

Note that `c1_1_1` is a direct descendant of the oldest ancestor `c1`. Is there a way I can do this easily using Java 8 Stream?

Comment: Aside : `container -> container.getParent() == null ? container : container.getParent()` won't recurse.

Comment: So you basically want to collapse the tree onto 2 levels, i.e. the first level being the keys and all subtrees being the respective values? Btw, why would c1 and c2 be their own descendants?

Comment: @Thomas they shouldn't, so I fixed that in my question. And I want all levels of children to collapse into a single list with their oldest ancestor (parent) as the key of the map. So children of children of children would have the same ancestor as the key.

Comment: @Naman is there a way to perform recursion easily to achieve the result I'm after?

Comment: @driima for that you might want to write your own method as a tree iterator *unless you find a root* while finding the parent.

Comment: Is there a specific need to do it in a stream? In my view this fits perfectly into a tree datastructure where a simple breadth first search can solve the problem.